# Does anyone know the source of "Don't abuse other people's god"?

Tags: source-identification, allah, other-religions

I don't know if this was in Qur'an or Hadith but I am sure I have read that Islam forbids talking bad about other people's god no matter how much you disagree, because it says what will you do if other people talk bad of Allah? Something of that order… does anyone know what could be the source of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The saying you're referring to is an ayah of the Qur'an, namely [Surat al-'An'Am 108](http://quran.com/6/108):

> **ولا تسبوا الذين يدعون من دون الله فيسبوا الله عدوا بغير علم** كذلك زينا لكل أمة عملهم ثم إلى ربهم مرجعهم فينبئهم بما كانوا يعملون
>
> **And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah , lest they insult Allah in enmity without knowledge.** Thus We have made pleasing to every community their deeds. Then to their Lord is their return, and He will inform them about what they used to do.
> <sup>--- Saheeh International</sup>

Comment: This translation is very difficult to understand and I am not sure if this is exactly what I am looking for. As far as I can understand, I don't see the theme that don't abuse others because they can abuse you the same way.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I find the translation perfectly understandable (there *are* alternate translations available at the link provided) and as far as I can tell it pretty much *exactly* answers your question.

Comment: I search more and you are right. I think the translation language was just a little difficult. I will accept this as answer, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An example in this regard can be given of Abu Bakr As-Siddik (may Allah be pleased with him), he commanded Usama Ibne Zaid (may Allah be pleased with him):

> “I command you to do 10 things: you must not kill a woman or a child, or an elderly person; do not cut down the trees, or vandalize homes, or wound a sheep or camel except if you must eat it; do not drown a palm tree, or burn it, do not be treacherous; do not be cowardly; and you will pass by people who have devoted themselves to monastery life; leave them alone with their devotions.” (Tarikh At-Tabari, V.3 p. 210)

([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/urn/409900) reference)

Answer (score 0):

Chapter (6) sūrat l-anʿām (The Cattle) Sahih International:

> And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah, lest they insult Allah in enmity without knowledge. Thus We have made pleasing to every community their deeds. Then to their Lord is their return, and He will inform them about what they used to do. (6:108)

(See [Islam Awakened](http://islamawakened.com/quran/6/108/) for further translations.)

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam, we are not like the typical internet forum. To learn more about this site and the stack exchange model I recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. I also suggest you to take a look at [answer] as your answer doesn't seem to give any improvement to the given answers here.