# Why are there imams that don't respect other religions?

Tags: other-religions, jews, respect

When someone said that there are Muslims that don't respect for example Jews, I said to him that it's because this Muslims didn't study the Quran because it says that in the Quran you need to respect other religions. Am I right? Correct me if I'm wrong. Then he said "but there are Imams, that supposedly they need to know everything about Islam and Quran and talk bad about Jews".

Can someone explain me and give an explanation to this please?

Comment: Where in the Quran does it say that it is required to respect other religions?

Comment: [Examples](http://pastebin.com/Tc1js3ax)

Comment: As written, this appears to be too opinion-based to practically answer: The reasons why any given imam preaches as they do is very dependent not only on exactly what flavour of Islam they follow, but also their own personal beliefs and/or the cultural norms of their congregation.

Comment: It is sometimes said, too much knowledge can lead you to 'kuffr'. So, the imams are in a high probability of getting into that state.

Comment: if it is **not** said, we should disrespect every other religion in Qur'an, then it is understood that we should respect every other religion (although some are foolish according to Islam like Paganism), unless stated other wise, e.g. as in 1st line of American Muslim's answer. [Here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24386/9123) is a sample. @Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right. You should only make supplication against enemies who are fighting against you.

Source: [Saudi Islamic Affairs](http://www.alwasatnews.com/3622/news/read/693083/1.html)

You can see that many scholars would make supplication against the Jews, this is totally wrong and shouldn't be done. This all stems from the Palestinian/Israeli issue.

Many people will generalize that all Jews = Israel and all of Israel = Jews, which is totally incorrect. You can make supplications against those who attack and kill Muslims, but do not generalize, which is I think what is happening here. This is similar to many Americans who say "Muslims are terrorists", yes there are some Muslims who are terrorists but compared to the Majority its a small amount. Muslims and some scholars are doing the same against the Jews.

We can also learn from the prophet PBUH when he went to Alaqaba to make Dawa to them and they ordered their children to throw rocks at the prophet as he was walking out. Allah gave him the option to destroy them but he instead asked for forgiveness incase some of their children might become Muslims and help the Muslim nation out.

Source: http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=53&ID=5462

As Muslims we should always be making Supplication to guide people to the straight path, not kill them.

Comment: I totally agree about what you are saying! But what would I argument to that person that said me that? By saying "talking bad" I meant not respecting. (but there are Imams, that supposedly they need to know everything about Islam and Quran and talk bad about Jews).

Answer (score 3):

Well being disrespectful towards other religions isn't what Islam teaches it's followers. The Prophet(SAW) would engage in discussion with the Jews and used to tell them that Musa(AS) was his brother (showing respect).

Islam encourages it's followers to feel pity for the blind people and help these people to develop the sense of sight. This means that a pious believer would see non-Muslims with a pitiful sight and would do whatever is possible to let them join the Ummah and get on Sirat-Al-Mustaqeem.

Criticism won't ever inspire others to come for a closer look. The Prophet(SAW) and later the Sahaba(RA) would buy their hearts with the ethics and etiquettes and then invite them to be like him(the Prophet(SAW).

Comment: Beautiful. Can't wait to see more of your answers!